# Phrases in the same family as "vice versa"

Tags: phrase-request, latin

I'm looking for phrases that are in the same vein as "vice versa". Not necessarily synonyms, like "conversely", but other phrases with a similar framework and origin. They don't have to be commonly used. (If they were, I'd probably have been able to find them).

To be more specific, I'm looking for Latin phrases that can be used in the same manner as "vice versa". In the same way that "vice versa" means "conversely", I figure there must be a similarly structured phrase that means "similarly", or something to that effect, as well as several others.

I am writing a character for a short story who grew up speaking Latin. I envision him using a lot of Latin phrases, as a remnant of his upbringing, however I cannot think of any at all.

I cannot give any examples, unfortunately, which is why I'm asking this question in the first place.

Comment: Voting to close. You are asking for ideas, not answers.

Comment: You might want to ask on [writing.se] for strategies for finding Latin phrases for your character. The [latin.se] folks might also be able to help. As it stands now, this isn't a question about English.

Comment: @ColleenV I see what you mean. If I'd realized those other SE sites existed, I probably would've gone to one of them instead. Hindsight, I suppose, is 20/20.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's still not clear what your intent is. Are you looking for short Latin phrases in general, that can be used in a similar way to *vice versa* as expressions that this character could sometimes utter—or are you looking for a phrase that, literally, means "similar"?

I started to compile a list of phrases, but it's simpler to just point you to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Latin_phrases_(full)) extensive resource.

Comment: Wow, somehow through all my googling I never came across that wikipedia post. Thanks so much for bringing that to my attention, it's exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

A phrase that comes to mind is *mutatis mutandis*, "after the things have been changed that needed to be changed". You could use it as in, we will apply the experience with have gained from assisting new mothers to new fathers, mutatis mutandis (it is expected that it is obvious what would need to be changed).

One expression that you could use in conversation is *pace tua*, literally "with your peace", which basically means "if you don't mind". It is used especially in situations where you're saying or assuming something that you know the other person probably doesn't agree with, so you're acknowledging that, but you still want to go on with whatever your point was.

Another common expression is *quod non*, "which not", which means "which is not the case". You can use it when you're describing an hypothetical situation: she would have helped me if she were a nice person, *quod non*.